# Intersection of boost::geometry::model::linestring with boost::geometry::model::polygon

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-geometry

I am trying to find the portion of a linestring that is inside of a polygon. I tried the `intersection` function, but it seems to just find the actual points of intersection rather than the portion of the linestring that is overlapping the polygon. Is there any way to get this object?

Here is a demo situation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/svg/svg_mapper.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/linestring.hpp>

using point_type = boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>;
using polygon_type = boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_type>;
using linestring_type = boost::geometry::model::linestring<point_type>;

int main()
{
    polygon_type polygon;

    polygon.outer().push_back(point_type{10,10});
    polygon.outer().push_back(point_type{12,10});
    polygon.outer().push_back(point_type{12,12});
    polygon.outer().push_back(point_type{10,12});
    polygon.outer().push_back(point_type{10,10});

    linestring_type linestring;
    linestring.push_back(point_type{11,9});
    linestring.push_back(point_type{11,11});
    linestring.push_back(point_type{13,11});

    // Expected intersections at (11, 10) and (12, 11)

    std::ofstream svg("both.svg");

    linestring_type output;
    boost::geometry::intersection(polygon, linestring, output);

    for(auto iter = output.begin(); iter != output.end(); ++iter) {
        std::cout << boost::geometry::get<0>(*iter) << " " << boost::geometry::get<1>(*iter) << std::endl;
    }
// The output is:
//    11 10
//    12 11

// But I want it to be:
//    11 10
//    11 11
//    12 11
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you must use a multi_linestring as the output type:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/linestring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/multi/geometries/multi_linestring.hpp>

using point_type = boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>;
using polygon_type = boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_type>;
using linestring_type = boost::geometry::model::linestring<point_type>;
using multi_linestring_type = boost::geometry::model::multi_linestring<linestring_type>;

int main()
{
    polygon_type polygon;

    polygon.outer().push_back(point_type{10,10});
    polygon.outer().push_back(point_type{10,12});
    polygon.outer().push_back(point_type{12,12});
    polygon.outer().push_back(point_type{12,10});
    polygon.outer().push_back(point_type{10,10});

    linestring_type linestring;
    linestring.push_back(point_type{11,9});
    linestring.push_back(point_type{11,11});
    linestring.push_back(point_type{13,11});

    // Expected intersections at (11, 10) and (12, 11)

    multi_linestring_type intersection;
    boost::geometry::intersection(polygon, linestring, intersection);

    for(auto intersectionIter = intersection.begin(); intersectionIter != intersection.end(); ++intersectionIter) {
        linestring_type intersectionPiece = *intersectionIter;
        std::cout << "Piece:" << std::endl;
        for(auto intersectionPieceIter = intersectionPiece.begin(); intersectionPieceIter != intersectionPiece.end(); ++intersectionPieceIter) {
            std::cout << boost::geometry::get<0>(*intersectionPieceIter) << " " << boost::geometry::get<1>(*intersectionPieceIter) << std::endl;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't "appear" like that. You're basically quoting the documentation here.

Comment: @sehe It is not at all obvious from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersection.html what types should be expected given the tons of combinations of possible input types. The first way I tried, I guess I would have expected the right answer when producing a linestring as output in this case since it is not a disjoint (multi) linestring. Anyhow, the example is now here for those that want to do this :)

Comment: From that link: _"GeometryOut &
Collection of geometries: (e.g. std::vector, std::deque, boost::geometry::multi*) of which the value_type fulfills a Point, LineString or Polygon concept, or it is the output geometry (e.g. for a box)"_ I really wonder what info could be added. Also, the example is already there on that very same documentation page.